# WebRequest/WebResponse Memory leak

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have an .Net Framework #4.0 application that makes a large number of web requests using the WebRequest/WebResponse classes , as i see it has memory leak (or maybe i am doing something wrong) 
I Wrote some small simple application that demonstrates this:

```
class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.gooogle.com");
            Init(webRequest);
            using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

                responseStream.ReadTimeout = 30;
                var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                var page = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                streamReader.Close();
                streamReader.Dispose();

                responseStream.Close();
                responseStream.Dispose();

                webResponse.Close();

                Console.WriteLine("Done");

                //GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }

     private static void Init (HttpWebRequest webRequest)
     {
         webRequest.Method = "GET";
         webRequest.Host = "www.gooogle.com";
         webRequest.UserAgent =
             "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB6.5; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3) chromeframe/5.0.375.62";
         webRequest.Accept =
             "application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*";
         webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
     }
}
```

The only one solution i came up with is use GC.Collect() (unmarked in example) , All the object are disposed , all streams are closed , am I missing something ?

I found something but i don't understand the reason , if i minimize Console the memory usage decreases and looks O.K , what can be the reason for that is there a problem with Conosole or WinForm , how can i fix it ?

Comment: How do you see it has a memory leak?

Comment: Stream and StreamReader also implement IDisposable.

Comment: if GC.Collect() fixes your leak it's not really a leak. It's totally normal that the GC hangs on to resources if there is no need to release them. Do you see performance implications when running your application for a long time? Does anything not perform as expected due to the increased memory usage? Did you profile the memory usage over time for an extended period?

Comment: removing `while(true)` would be a good start w.r.t memory management.

Comment: You don't need to call Close if you're also calling Dispose, but you *should* put the response stream and StreamReader in a `using` statement.

Comment: I've run this sample code against .NET versions 2, 3.5, and 4 and am unable to reproduce any apparent memory leaks - it actually works surprisingly well given the tight loop, which is probably due to the IO Completion waits. Under profiling you can see that the majority of allocations (> 90%) are for the strings generated by ReadToEnd().

Answer (score 5):

You're allocating memory in a tight loop. You probably don't have a memory leak, you have a poorly behaved application (in the sense that it's using up lots of system resources for no reason.)

The garbage collector is not going to interrupt your loop in order to compact freed memory unless it has to due to memory pressure. The simple fix would be to introduce a delay between iterations of the loop (could be as simple as Thread.Sleep, though I don't recommend that.)

Once your program is not working so hard to consume all available CPU time it should allow the GC to run more frequently.

Comment: @Tom You're actually correct, but for the wrong reason. It isn't a tight loop because the GetResponse method invokes a [IOCP wait](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232637/scaling-up-multiple-httpwebrequests/3327671#3327671) which frees the process to do other work (like garbage collection.)

Comment: ReadToEnd() just reads bytes out of the stream into a String object. There's no IOCP necessary because the response has already been read off the port. You can use Read with a delay between each byte while watching network traffic with Ethereal or similar to verify: the network stream will "download" the full response before you finish reading it. In other words, it doesn't wait to request packets until you've asked for them - GetResponse() retrieves the entire response immediately.

Comment: Really? I find that rather unlikely to be true in all cases. Granted, you will observe this for smaller transfers, but consider for example the case of a 16gb download delivered over http. Or an http audio or video stream.

Comment: try this for instance:

`HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

 request.Method = "GET";

 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

 var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

 using (var fileStream = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\myfile.avi"))

 {
     var buffer = new byte[8192];

     while (true)

     {
          var bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
          if (bytesRead <= 0)
              break;
          fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
     }
 }
`

Comment: from

([how-do-i-stream-data-from-an-httpresponse-to-the-console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238288/how-do-i-stream-data-from-an-httpresponse-to-the-console))

Comment: @Tom - You need to monitor the network traffic while **not** reading from the stream in order to prove the theory. However, if you consider the asynchronous BeginGetResponse and EndGetResponse methods designed for large downloads, that is pretty strong evidence that it is GetResponse that actually retrieves the data, not reading from the stream.

Comment: Did you try running the code? Try it with an endless stream. You will see that it does not read the 'entire' response at GetResponse. GetResponse simply return an object that allows you to read from the stream. Put a breakpoint at GetResponse and step over it. You will see that I am right :)

Comment: Also, the async methods aren't so much designed for large downloads, as to allow for non-blocking code which is important for high performance applications, so as to not waste resources by using threads that are not needed.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
while (true)
{
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://www.gooogle.com");
    Init(webRequest);
    using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            responseStream.ReadTimeout = 30;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var page = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: "using" is the same as manually disposing the resource which i did (so i don't see how it will help ) , but anyway i did the test the result is the same .:(

Comment: "using" is not the same when an exception occurs.

Comment: @JohnSaunders so what would you change in code then to handle exception as well? thanks...

Comment: I would not handle exceptions in that code. There is nothing to "handle". There is nothing that can be fixed. One should only catch exceptions which can be handled. Logging should be handled at the top level of the application (more or less), but that's about all in the code above.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this ([source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2855735/memory-optimization-for-a-large-httpwebrequest-post-or-put-based-on-ne)):

> **Symptoms**
>
> When you use the `HttpWebRequest` class to send lots of data for a HTTP POST or PUT request, the request may fail on a computer that is running the Microsoft .NET Framework. Additionally, you may receive an out-of-memory exception.
>
> You may notice that the application that uses the `HttpWebRequest` class consumes lots of memory. When you use Performance Monitor to monitor the application that uses the HttpWebRequest class, the Private Bytes count will continue to increase as data is sent.
>
> **Cause**
>
> This issue occurs because the .NET Framework buffers the outgoing data by default when you use the HttpWebRequest class. KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908573 documents the original issue.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> To work around this issue, set the `HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering` property to `false`. By doing this, outgoing data (entity body) for the POST or the PUT request will not be buffered in memory.
>
> In versions of Microsoft .NET Framework earlier than 4.5, setting `HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering` property to `false` would sometimes result in errors when uploading data to authenticated endpoints. For example, you might encounter a System.Net.WebException with the message "This request requires buffering data to succeed". However on deeper investigation the response associated with the exception actually indicates a status code of System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized (401). KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908573 documents a workaround of pre-authentication and KeepAlive connection to handle 401 response.
>
> Unlike Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0, Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 adds new design functionality for the `HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering` property. The new functionality can handle the authentication scenario directly as long as the Expect100Continue feature is enabled. The default `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue` value is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we found a leak too. The solution is... be careful what you do with this thing. Consider not using it. I believe it has... issues (at least in 3.5, presumably other versions too). Oh, and dont forget to report it/ vote on it at Microsoft Connect.

Comment: I just performed test and cant detect memory leak. Application's memory growed up for 5MB during 1min and after that stops. So I suppose that there is no memory leak.

Comment: Have you tried creating lots of them on different threads though?

Comment: I've just tried out sample app with 5 threads and in this case it has increased whole app memory for 12MB during first 1-2min and after that it have been working during ~3min without any changes in memory amount. After I've add `GC.Collect()` to thread routine it become less memory consuming. So all my tests gave me similar behavour - app increases its memory for constatn amount and didn't face permanent memory growing. But might be my tests differ from yours?

Comment: I will endeavour to get back to you with some proof of my assertion. The results showing this were some time ago and I do not have the code here. If I remember correctly, it was only apparent after several hours of extremely intensive use on multiple threads. For most applications, this is not a problem.